# How can I set the y-axes to the same scale for a multi-plot grid in plotly python

Tags: plotly-python, yaxis

I have a csv file with performance metrics and in order to plot CPU Load per week for a 4 week period, I use a multi-plot plotly package in python. Here's the code below. The problem is the load varies each week and the y-axis is different for each week. How can I ensure it is consistent for all the weeks?

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2,subplot_titles=("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4"))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=df_load1[:7]['date'], y=df_load1[:7]['avg_values']),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=df_load1[7:14]['date'], y=df_load1[7:14]['avg_values']),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=df_load1[14:22]['date'], y=df_load1[14:22]['avg_values']),
    row=2, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=df_load1[22:29]['date'], y=df_load1[22:29]['avg_values']),
    row=2, col=2
)
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="CPU load usage for Node1 per week ; Metric - node_load1", yaxis=dict(title="Avg num of CPUs"))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

As a full example building on py_noob's try shared_yaxes=True or shared_yaxes='all' might be better in this case e.g.

```
fig=make_subplots(rows=3, cols=4,
                  subplot_titles=(outcomes),
                  vertical_spacing=0.1,
                  horizontal_spacing=0.1,
                  shared_yaxes='all'
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the helpful hints in this link: https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/plotly.subplots.html

`shared_yaxis=True` ensures there is only one y-axis for multi-plots.

Comment: just worth highlighting there is a typo above should be shared_yaxes=True  or shared_yaxes='all' might be better in this case